# Can I have a string containing a delegate that is evaluated at runtime?

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

Can I have a string that contains a delegate that gets expanded at various times during runtime?

```
$pattern = "(?m)^INFO\:(?:\s|\t)*$({script:$marker})\:(?:\s|\t)*(?<url>.*)$"
$marker = "Some marker value"
:
#Do something with the resulting pattern containing the marker value
:
$marker = "Some other marker value"
:
#Do something with the pattern having the new marker value
```

and so on... I'd prefer not to have to keep redefining the string... or having a function that builds it. It seems so much more succinct if I could just have a few characters in the string that get evaluated when the string is needed vs. when the $pattern value is set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do

```
$pattern = {"(?m)^INFO\:(?:\s|\t)*($script:marker)\:(?:\s|\t)*(?<url>.*)$"}
```

and then later use

```
$pattern.invoke()
```

(Assuming you want $script:marker to be the characters that get set later, your original example has $({script:$marker}), but that won't work if it is supposed to do what I think it should ;))

In general: Define the term as Scriptblock using {} and later .invoke() to evaluate it.

Just make sure there is no confusion about the types within the curly brackets, otherwise you might get some strange results...